# How can I create a map of strings to functions in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures

I am working on [Make a Lisp](https://github.com/kanaka/mal/blob/master/process/guide.md) to learn Rust.

As part of [the evaluator step](https://github.com/kanaka/mal/blob/master/process/guide.md#step-2-eval) I need to create an associative structure mapping strings (or whatever) to functions. In languages I'm more familiar with (Ruby, Clojure) I would simply define anonymous functions in a hashmap, eg

```clj
{ :+ (fn [a b] (+ a b))
  :- (fn [a b] (- a b)) } ; etc
```

In Rust, this isn't possible because of the type error `expected closure, found a different closure`.

```rust
let repl_env = HashMap::new();

repl_env.insert("+", |a, b| a + b);
repl_env.insert("-", |a, b| a - b); // expected closure, found a different closure
```

I guess what's happening here is

- the compiler is inferring the types in the `HashMap` as `<String, WhateverTypeTheFirstClosureIs>`
- the second closure doesn't have the same time because as the compiler error goes on to say, `no two closures, even if identical, have the same type`?

I can add types to the arguments and thus make the return type inferrable, but this doesn't help — I assume I need to somehow annotate the types of the closures themselves? I can't find a way to do this in the docs. The error suggests Boxing, but wrapping the closures in `Box::new` doesn't help. (I've never `Box`ed before).

I'm also wondering whether Rust closures in a `HashMap` are the right thing to use here. Should I maybe use an `enum` of some sort? (I'll want to dynamically add things later when I'm adding user-defined functions to my lisp, so I assume not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't actually need *closures* here since you're not closing over anything, you're just using anonymous static functions.

That means you can just cast your anonymous functions to function pointers and it'll work fine e.g.

```rust
let mut repl_env: HashMap<_, fn(i32, i32) -> i32> = HashMap::new();

repl_env.insert("+", |a, b| a + b);
repl_env.insert("-", |a, b| a - b);
```

If you did need closures, then you'd have to use some sort of dynamic dispatch (as each closure is an entirely different type), generally something along the lines of `Box e.g.

```rust
let mut repl_env: HashMap<_, Box<dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> i32>> = HashMap::new();

repl_env.insert("+", Box::new(|a, b| a + b));
repl_env.insert("-", Box::new(|a, b| a - b));
```

That latter version is what the error message talks about: boxing the closure [and] (in this case) making it a trait object.

> Should I maybe use an enum of some sort?

Using an enum might be a good idea as eventually you'll have functions with different signatures: here you're limited to the signature of `(i32, i32) -> i32`. Though you can alternatively update the universal signature to e.g. `(Values) -> Value` and internally perform dispatch / typechecking / ...

> I'll want to dynamically add things later when I'm adding user-defined functions to my lisp, so I assume not.

If you want to keep the distinction between "native" and "user" functions, you can always have a variant which stores the result of evaluating a user function in your enum. You'll need a way to distinguish them anyway since at the end of the day the evaluator won't call them the same way.

Though I would think the usual method is to make all visible functions uniformly "userland", and implement those in terms of builtins (which may be distinguished syntactically, or special forms, or even pattern-matched by the compiler, and may or may not be accessible to userland).

I don't know how Lisps usually do it at the root, but e.g. you could have the interpreter evaluate the terms of

```
(+ a b)
```

and check that `+` is the known / standard function and `a` and `b` are known compatible types, then do the operation internally without actually calling anything.

The fun bit is that you can provide a properly defined `+` function as

```lisp
(define (+ a b)
  (+ a b))
```

which looks nonsensical at first glance since it should recurse on itself, but the inner node can be pattern-matched by the interpreter and so this serves as a hook for higher-order functions.

That is how many Smalltalks handled this, for instance. Non-literal sends would land into the trampoline method, which would then bounce into the built-in for the operation, invisibly.

Comment: this is fascinating, and I now understand the type issue — thank you. to be sure I understand you correctly, should I consider an enum like `ReplEnv` with members like `Add(MalType, MalType)` and add some sort of `call` trait? Then build everything else on top of that, ie decompose user-defined functions into stacks of builtins?